# Problem with UICollectionView delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to use an `UICollectionView`, it's being shown on the view, but the delegate methods are not being called. Here's how I'm trying to do:

On Storyboard, I have a `UITableViewController` which has a `TableView` and a `UIView` like this:

[image]

I've created an outlet for the `UIView` on my `UITableViewController` class:

```
class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: UIView!

}
```

And on `viewDidLoad()` function, I'm instantiating the `UIViewController` class which will be the delegate and datasource of my `UICollectionView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let bannerViewController = BannerViewController()
    bannerView.addSubview(bannerViewController.view)

    bannerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Here's the full code of `BannerViewController` class:

```
class BannerViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 125)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .cyan

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

}

extension BannerViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

}

extension BannerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)
    }

}
```

The `UICollectionView` is being instantiated and appears on the view, as we can see on the cyan box here:

[image]

But the delegate methods `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt` are not being called. And I have registered `BannerViewController` as the datasource and delegate of the `UICollectionView`, so I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold a strong reference to ( make it as instance var )

```
var bannerViewController:BannerViewController!
```

---

Also properly add it

```
bannerViewController = BannerViewController()
addChildViewController(bannerViewController)
view.addSubview(bannerViewController.view)
bannerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    bannerViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.leadingAnchor),
    bannerViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.trailingAnchor),
    bannerViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor),
    bannerViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.bottomAnchor)
])
bannerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Also don't forget

```
extension BannerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Comment: Holding a strong reference to `bannerViewController ` has solved the issue, thanks!